# Devise Login w/ Multiple Emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am storing all of my users' emails in a separate table. Each user has_many emails. The problem I am having is how to make devise use these emails for logging in instead of looking in the users table. I know I need to put some kind of condition in my find_for_database_authentication method but I can't seem to figure it out. I tried something like the following but had no luck:

```
login = conditions.delete(:login)
where(conditions).where(:emails => { :name => login }).first
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be possible to use something other than the email addresses to login?  If you could allow users to log in with a username or something like that there is a [devise wiki article on the subject](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address).

Answer (score 4):

Not sure I did this the right way, but I just created a new strategy in config/initializers/devise.rb

```
require 'devise/strategies/authenticatable'
module Devise
  module Strategies
    class MultipleEmailAuthenticatable < Authenticatable
      def authenticate!
        email = Email.find_by_email_address(authentication_hash[:email])
        unless email
          fail(:invalid)
          return
        end
        resource = valid_password? && email.member
        if validate(resource){ resource.valid_password?(password) }
          resource.after_database_authentication
          success!(resource)
        elsif !halted?
          fail(:invalid)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Where do you override your find_for_database_authentication method?